# Objective-c: The xib loaded from code is not the same on the project

Tags: objective-c, ipad, interface

I have problem with my project. I have an interface file which has two buttons but somehow when i run the application the interface has only one button. I know the interface is not the same the one on the project.

Does anyone know what is on about ?

Please help

Comment: How do you know the interface is not the same one on the project? What exactly do you mean by that? The most likely scenario is that the other button is off screen somewhere because of incorrect layout constraints.

Comment: Try logging the loaded views. In `viewDidLoad:` or `viewDidAppear:` write this, `NSLog(@"%@", self.view.subviews);`. If the views are not loaded check Brent Royal-Gordon's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try holding the `Option` key on your keyboard then going to `Product > Clean Build Folder`. If that doesn't work, you either made a typo somewhere or theres something wrong with your xib.

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning your project (Product > Clean) and deleting the app from the device or simulator.

If that doesn't help, make sure one of the buttons isn't positioned so far down or to the right that it ends up beyond the edge of the screen. (That's particularly likely to be a problem if you're designing the interface in one orientation and testing it in another.) If that turns out to be the issue, take a look at your resizing masks or autolayout constraints and see if you can't change the layout to keep that button on screen.

Answer (score 0):

How you created 2 button? (by xib file? or write some code)

Carefully, if a object is created from xib file, iOS will call this method:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
```

Good luck!